# Check if a Xiaomi should vibrate for calls

Tags: android, call, android-vibration

The question is Xiaomi-specific. I know that there are similar questions regarding the devices on normal Android OS.

There are different ways to understand if an Android phone is on 100% Vibration-only mode or if its "Vibrate on call" is turned on for the Normal mode.

The issue with Xiaomi is... that no one works. At least, from the list I have:

```
  /**
   * This method should tell us if the vibration is on in the Android System settings
   */
  public boolean checkVibrationIsOn() {
    boolean status = false;
    if (isInVibrationMode()
        || isVibrationOnHacky()
        || isVibrationOnDeprecated()) {
      status = true;
    }
    return status;
  }

  /**
   * Check if the phone is in Vibration mode
   */
  private boolean isInVibrationMode() {
    return audioManager.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE;
  }

  /**
   * Use a direct access to get status of Vibration. Works not on all kinds of phones
   */
  private boolean isVibrationOnHacky() {
    return 0 != Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.VIBRATE_WHEN_RINGING,0);
  }

  /**
   * Use a deprecated method to get status of Vibration. It was deprecated so usual apps can't use it
   * but it works on some devices
   */
  private boolean isVibrationOnDeprecated() {
    return audioManager.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL
        && audioManager.shouldVibrate(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER);
  }
```

Does anybody know how to check the "Vibrate" catefory's "Also vibrate for calls" and "Vibrate in silent mode" flags on Xiaomi devices?

Answer (score 1):

On Xiaomi device there are two settings for vibration: vibrate_in_normal and vibrate_in_silent.
You will need to analyse RingerMode and call Settings.System.getInt() with proper constant:

```
if (audioManager.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
    return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "vibrate_in_normal",0);
else
    return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "vibrate_in_silent",0);
```

Comment: Sorry, but this not working. Both getInt() returns default value. Tested in Redmi Note 9 Pro, Android 10, MIUI 11.

Comment: just checked on a new device, and by default they were empty.
When I ran cmd "adb shell settings list system" it didn't contain those to settings in result.
After I change for the first time, settings are present
could you,please, check that after changing the setting appears? 
you can run "adb shell settings list system" command for it.

Comment: OK, tested again. Result: if these parameters are not in Setting.System, default for both is "enabled". Telephone application saves these parameters into Settings.System. "Vibrate for call" change both "vibrate_in_normal" and "vibrate_when _ringing". But Xiaomi uses "vibrate_in_normal". Interesting. :-) @user1081783 thank you very much.

Comment: Hm, but is not possible to change it: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot keep your settings in the secure settings. Maybe only in rooted device.

Comment: Looks that in some version Xiaomi made changes and modify VIBRATE_WHEN_RINGING setting, so no need to specific handling of xiaomi devices. The code from question should work as it is.